# Find all strings matching REGEX in multiple Word 2013 document and paste into a single, specific Word 2013 document

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word, copy, paste

Spent a week trying to figure this out, so far, so I'm not just jumping here first - and all Microsoft sites tend to focus on Excel which seems to be non-appropriate for what I'm doing:

I'm attempting to use this VBA script to open up multiple WORD files, in succession, run a Find/Selection to grab a specific pattern, and then copy all occurrences into another WORD file.

This code is a mix of something I found online (though can't recall where, at this point) and my own tinkering.  I've been able to DEBUG.PRINT the correct output, but no way to continue to move through my file to copy specific lines and then paste them.  I feel it has something to do with the .Activate calls:

```
Sub x()

Dim GetStr(5000) As String

Const wdStory = 4
Const wdExtend = 1

'Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\...\filename.CDS", Visible:=True)
'Set Doc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\...\filename.CDS")

Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With MyDialog
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.CDS", 1
.AllowMultiSelect = True

i = 2 'set to 2 in order to offset the open word window that houses the VBA

If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
        i = i + 1
    Next
    i = i - 1
End If

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\...\filename.docx")

For j = 2 To i Step 1

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(GetStr(j))
'Debug.Print (objWord.Documents(1).Name)

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Find.Forward = True
objSelection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
objSelection.Find.Text = "DEFINE"

Do While True

    objSelection.Find.Execute
    Debug.Print (objSelection)
    If objSelection.Find.Found Then
        objSelection.EndOf wdStory, wdExtend     'get selection
        strText = objSelection.Copy              'strText = selection copied to clipboard, no value     (like an inline function)
        Set selectionToPaste = objWord.Selection 'selectionToPaste is literally the clipboard
        'objWord.Documents(2).Activate
        'Debug.Print ("->'Activated Window': " + objWord.ActiveDocument.Name)
        'Debug.Print ("selectionToPaste = " + selectionToPaste)
        selectionToPaste.Paste
        'objWord.Documents(1).Activate
        objSelection.Find.Execute
    Else
        objWord.ActiveDocument.Save
        objWord.ActiveWindow.Close
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop

Next

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

OP here - Solved my own problem utilizing a loop.

```
Sub x()

Dim GetStr(5000) As String
**Dim iCounter As Integer**
Const wdStory = 4
Const wdExtend = 1

'Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\...\filename.CDS", Visible:=True)
'Set Doc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\...\filename.CDS")

Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With MyDialog
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.CDS", 1
.AllowMultiSelect = True

i = 2 'set to 2 in order to offset the open word window that houses the VBA

If .Show = -1 Then
    For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
        i = i + 1
    Next
    i = i - 1
End If

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True
objWord.Documents.Open ("C:\Users\lidm3b2\Desktop\gar\2.docx")

For j = 2 To i Step 1

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(GetStr(j))
'Debug.Print (objWord.Documents(1).Name)

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Find.Forward = True
objSelection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
objSelection.Find.Text = "DEFINE"

**iCounter = 0**

Do While True
    **For iLoopCounter = 0 To iCounter Step 1
        objSelection.Find.Execute
    Next**
    Debug.Print (objSelection)
    If objSelection.Find.Found Then
        objSelection.EndOf wdStory, wdExtend     'get selection
        strText = objSelection.Copy              'strText = selection copied to clipboard, no value (like an inline function)
        Set selectionToPaste = objWord.Selection 'selectionToPaste is literally the clipboard
        objWord.Documents(2).Activate
        'Debug.Print ("->'Activated Window': " + objWord.ActiveDocument.Name)
        'Debug.Print ("selectionToPaste = " + selectionToPaste)
        objWord.Selection.Paste
        objWord.Documents(1).Activate
    **iLoopCounter = iLoopCounter + 1**
        objSelection.Find.Execute
    Else
        objWord.ActiveDocument.Save
        objWord.ActiveWindow.Close 'have to close for the hardcode on "...Documents(1)..." and 2 to work.
        Exit Do
    End If

Loop

Next

End With

End Sub
```